# LinkedList java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException : Index: 0, Size: 1

Tags: java, linked-list

So i'm currently making a game in java for a college proyect and following a tutorial i found on youtube i'm using a LinkedList to order all my classes that are heirs of my GameObject class, everything runs "smoothly" without any problems most of the times, yet from time to time, usually when there are a lot of objects in my game, the program crashes and sends me a:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: 
Index: 1277, Size: 1278
at java.base/java.util.LinkedList.checkElementIndex(LinkedList.java:559)
at java.base/java.util.LinkedList.get(LinkedList.java:480)
at game.Boss1_wings.collision(Boss1_wings.java:1319)
at game.Boss1_wings.tick(Boss1_wings.java:538)
at game.Handler.tick(Handler.java:15)
at game.Game.tick(Game.java:123)
at game.Game.run(Game.java:84)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
AL lib: alc_cleanup: 1 device not closed
```

Obviously the size and index number depend on the objects that are currently on my game and yet it sometimes crashes yust with about 30-40 or even down to 0-10 objects.

i've already tried limiting the number of objects that enter the linked list by calling my object.size() with a -1 or initializing it before it enters the iteration for every object. And even tho the object.size()-1 seems to allow the program and game to run, it seems to crash even more frecuently then normally, so it is not a sollution.

this is basically my handler class, the one that uses the LinkedList and runs through it in the "tick()" method.

```
public static int type=0;
public static int Ulti=0;
LinkedList<GameObject> object= new LinkedList<GameObject>();


public void tick(){
    for (int i=0 ; i<object.size() ; i++) {
        GameObject tempObject = object.get(i);
        tempObject.tick();
    }
    if (HUD.HEALTH==0){
        Handler.Ulti=0;
        setType(0);
    }
}

public void render(Graphics g) {
    for (int i=0 ; i<object.size() ; i++) {
        GameObject tempObject = object.get(i);
        tempObject.render(g);
    }
}
public void addObject(GameObject object){
    this.object.add(object);
}

public void removeObject(GameObject object){
    this.object.remove(object);
}

public void setType(int type) {
    this.type = type;
}
public int getType() {
    return type;
}
```

i basically expect the program not to crash... with the error that im getting.
One of the solutions i thought about was to get more threads running at the same time, yet i don't know how to do this.
Sorry if bad english.

Comment: You're most probably accessing your list from multiple threads without properly synchronizing. You need to learn about concurrency, which is a complex topic, requiring extreme care and rigor.

Comment: :/ if it is way too complex it might not be an alternative, but my proyect is already waaay more that what i needed for my project and at this point i just want to make a good game... thx for the help tho :D